# how can I install CUDA on linux on a custom path (not in /usr/local)

Tags: linux, cuda

Is there any good guide about how to install CUDA on linux
on a custom path (other than /usr/local) ?
I have already installed one version and I would like to install a second one.
Also, how can I know which one is the best for me according to my GPU?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FINALLY,
I found this on the official documentation,

*The Runfile installation asks where you wish to install the Toolkit and the Samples
during an interactive install. If installing using a non-interactive install, you can use the*
*--toolkitpath and --samplespath parameters to change the install location:*

```
./runfile.run --silent \

--toolkit --toolkitpath=/my/new/toolkit \

--samples --samplespath=/my/new/samples
```

*The RPM packages don't support custom install locations though the package managers*
*(Yum and Zypper), but it is possible to install the RPM packages in custom locations*
*using rpm's --relocate parameter:*

```
$ rpm --install --relocate /usr/local/cuda-6.5=/my/new/toolkit rpmpackage.rpm
```

*The Deb packages don't support custom install locations through the package manager*
*(apt), but it is possible to install the Deb packages in custom locations using dpkg's --
instdir parameter*

```
$ dpkg --instdir=/my/new/toolkit --install debpackage.deb
```

*For RPM and Deb packages, you will need to install the packages in the correct order
of dependency; normally the package managers take care of this automatically. For example, if package "foo" has a dependency on package "bar", you should install
package "bar" first, and package "foo" second. You can check the dependencies of a RPM or Deb package as follows*

```
$ rpm -qRp rpmpackage.rpm

$ dpkg -I debpackage.deb | grep Depends
```